# http authorization not sent for resources on page?

Tags: http, https, authorization

I'm successfully setting up an HTTP Digest Authorization between the web browser and the server.  But some of the resources on the same page to the same host are failing because the browser isn't sending the authorization for them.

For example,

- Page `https://myhost/A/B/C/D/E/` is loaded, browser sends `Authorization` header.
- Page contains IMG ref to `https://myhost/A/B/C/D/E/F.JPG`,  browser sends `Authorization` header.
- Page also contains IMG ref to `https://myhost/A/B.JPG`, but for some reason browser does not send `Authorization` header.  Server returns `401 Unauthorized` but browser does not retry with authorization or pop up a username/password field, it simply displays the "broken image" icon.

I have looked a bit at how HTTP Authorization and I don't see anything mentioned regarding the scope of a request.  Nevertheless, because I am explicitly sending back a 401 if the browser doesn't send `Authorization` for a request, I would expect it should work.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

HTML authorization is governed by [RFC 2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), which in section 1.2 says:

> The realm value (case-sensitive), in combination with the canonical
>   root URL (the absoluteURI for the server whose abs_path is empty; see
>   section 5.1.2 of [2]) of the server being accessed, defines the
>   protection space.”. Later in the same section it says: “The protection
>   space determines the domain over which credentials can be
>   automatically applied. If a prior request has been authorized, the
>   same credentials MAY be reused for all other requests within that
>   protection space for a period of time determined by the authentication
>   scheme, parameters, and/or user preference.

So as long as the two URLS are in the same "protection space" the browser is supposed to resend the same credentials.  However in this case the problem is that they are not.  If authorization occurs in the `https://myhost/A/B/C/D/E/` space, then the browser may not see a need to send authorization for `https://myhost/A/B.JPG`.

Section 2 mentions:

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
>   the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
>   are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
>   the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
>   corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in that
>   space without receipt of another challenge from the server.

So the solution is to make sure that the `WWW-Authenticate` header sent by the server sends a `domain=/` entry, so that everything under that will be considered in the same protection space.